# method to get default location

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

In sale.order.line I have field location_id and I want that it would fill up by default. the problem is that i get `TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`with this code and `self` always comes empty. if I add `if self.product_id:` to my method it just stops working.

```py
    class SaleOrderLine(models.Model):
            _inherit = "sale.order.line"

    def _get_default_location(self):
                return self.env['stock.location'].search(['location_id', '=', self.product_id.warehouse_id.out_type_id.default_location_src_id.id], limit=1)

    location_id = fields.Many2one('stock.location', 'Location', default=_get_default_location)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default methods always have empty recordsets. You won't get any data there, except you find out to get something into the context before the default method is called.

But in your example you just could use the onchange method for product_id. I bet you won't need a location_id without a product on a line. So override the original onchange method for product_id on `sale.order.line` and always set your desired default location_id. (I think it's called `product_id_change`)

```py
def product_id_change(self):
    res = super(SaleOrderLine, self).product_id_change()
    if self.product_id:
        self.location_id = # your search here
    else:
        self.location_id = False
    return res
```